# SharePoint 2010 BCS stops working after a while

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, wcf

A little background: we are using the BCS with an external content type to expose external content we provide using a WCF service. We have a webpart that uses the external content type to display a list of data. Everything is working fine, but suddenly it stops. We cannot isolate the problem properly and are having a really hard time even reproducing it.

When the error occurs, we have checked our WCF service with a client application and there is no problem there, so we suspect it's actually the BCS that's giving us trouble.

We have to restart the BCS to get it working again. Sometimes it's enough to close the browser, causing me to think it might have to do with some session expering. I have googled to the end of the internet with the messages the ULS viewer is giving us, but to no avail.

Another relevent point might be that the user is logged in to the Sharepoint environment. It's aware of the users identity, but somehow can't make the trip to the BCS anymore. This can happen after two clicks, but also after using it for a couple of hours ;-(

I know this is very abstract, but it's what I have to work with. I can provide more details, but I am hoping this rings a bell to someone.

All suggestions are very very welcome, as I am fresh out of ideas.

**EDIT** I might be able to add the ULS trace later on, but I'm having difficulty to determine which messages are actually relevant.

The problem appears to popup everytime we do an IIS reset. Our WCF service is being deployed as part of the SharePoint web application. The BCS has trouble impersonation at times (I think), causing an access problem to the WCF service.

**We moved the WCF service to an anonymous SharePoint web application** and it looks like this resolved the issue (further testing needed). This obviously is a workaround, but may provide a hint as to what the actual problem is?

Thanx, syg

Comment: Can you provide a more complete stack trace from the endpoint not listening exception there might be more information buried in a nested exception. Even better would be a fragment from the ULS log. It might also be worth checking the Windows Event log to see if there are any errors from the same time period.

Answer (score 1):

We had issues that another co-installed product replaced the [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) causing SSL Trust issues when communicating with the Secure Store service

This caused calls to BCS Entity Finders to throw exceptions.

Can you give any more information on the exact exception being thrown or provide some log file fragments.

If not then all I can suggest is to turn logging onto verbose and check the ULS log at the time the issue occurs.

Comment: When it the connection get's faulted somewhere, we get an error that no endpoint was listening at 
http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc

This service isn't running, so it's obvious it can't find the endpoint. The reason it's looking for in the firstplace is unclear to me. 
1. It works
2. Mystery happens
3. Heeey, I'm trying to read security info in your request, but I can't find it. Let's go to the security token service.